# Strings with double quotes and variables within

Tags: java, string, escaping

I'm trying to use sendEmail on a Win7 machine to send out an email. It works fine but I decided to send the subject and message as arguments to the sendEmail method.

Because the subject and body contain a dash characters, sendEmail is not reacting correctly since it makes use of the dash char too. What I need to do is add double quotes around the subjectText variable and the messageText variable.

```
    stdin.println("sendemail -t " + emailAddresses + " -f admin@xyz.com -u " +
        subjectText + " -m " + messageText + " -s smtp.gmail.com:25");
```

I tried this:

```
stdin.println("sendemail -t " + emailAddresses + " -f admin@xyz.com -u " + \" +
       subjectText + "\"+ -m "\"+ messageText + "\" -s smtp.gmail.com:25");
```

But it didn't work.

The output needs to look something like this:

```
"sendemail -t tome@isp.com -f admin@xyz.com -u "Subject with a - char" -m "message body with a - char" -s smtp.gmail.com:25"
```

The cmd is getting displayed in my Eclipse console.

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others said, the escaped quotes need to be inside the literal.

As some extra food for thought; when creating strings with variables in it can sometimes be neater or less complex by using `String.format()` or using a `StringBuilder`.

As an example using `String.format`

```
String str = String.format(
    "sendemail -t %s -f admin@xyz.com -u \"%s\" -m \"%s\" -s smtp.gmail.com:25",    
     emailAddress, subjectText, messageText);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your escaped double-quotes need to be inside of a string literal themselves.  Try

```
stdin.println("sendemail -t " + emailAddresses + " -f admin@xyz.com -u \"" +
   subjectText + "\" -m \"" + messageText + "\" -s smtp.gmail.com:25");
```